# Webrtc fails on cellurar but works on Wifi (also different wifis)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webrtc, p2p

My Problem is that I cant create a successful connection between an Android App (LTE / 4G / 3G) and a Deskop app written in JavaScript (Connected to a WiFi).

Caller: Android App
Callee: Desktop Web App

I'm using STUN & TURN Server from XirSys(Demo Account).

There are the following scenarios:

1. Android App(Wifi1) -> Desktop App(Wifi1) - working
2. Android App(Wifi2) -> Desktop App(Wifi1) - working
3. Android App(Lte/4G/3G) -> Desktop app(Wifi1) - not working

Strange thing is that the IceCandidates are swapped.
On the Callee side it throws iceGatheringState Complete.
On the Caller side it first throws complete then failed.

I'm would be appreciated for every help i get.
If i have to post any further details (Code, Logs, etc) just tell me.

Kind regards

**Android Output:**

```
12-12 11:27:40.841 4211-4238/xx.webrtc_android E/onIceConnectionChange: FAILED
12-12 11:27:40.841 4211-4238/xx.webrtc_android E/RESTARTING: PEERCONNECTION
12-12 11:27:40.844 4211-4238/xx.webrtc_android E/onIceConnectionChange: CLOSED
```

JMD

EDIT:
Maybe I have expressed the problem the wrong way...
I CAN connect from LTE / 4G / 3G to my server which runs on a public ip address.

The Problem is that i cant establish a peer 2 peer connection when my Android App is running on LTE/ 4G / 3G Network.
I'm able to exchange the Candidates over a SignalR Socket but it always changes the IceconnectionState to failed on the callee side.

ANOTHER EDIT:

WebRTC Internals are showing the following

[LTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK5nl.png)

[Wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysZNu.png)

Seems like that the problem is that no matching candidates...

Comment: networking basics: yes, **you cannot** without public IP and it has nothing to do with android ...

Comment: @Selvin My Server is running on a public IP Address. I forgot to mention that. So your answer isn't solving the problem...

Comment: @Selvin 
It works if you test it on the AppRTC Example. So it must give a way to do this. Maybe my Turn Servers not working the way I want to. I'm trying to set up a Coturn Server on cygwin atm... I'll give a response if its working.

Comment: @John it's not likely to be a TURN server issue.  TURN servers are very simple creatures.  It would help if you could somehow get a capture of the network packets, as it's incredibly difficult to reason the issue without seeing it.  The likelihood is you're missing something in your client code.

Comment: @LeeSylvester 
Thats exactly what I thought in the first step because over wifi it works all perfect. Some silly question how can I capture the network pakets? Is there a feature in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I have added some `xirsys stun/turn` servers and it works now.
It shows that there was just a stun server needed in the overview panel. 
WebRTC Internals is showing the following:

```
Statistics Conn-audio-1-0
timestamp   12/15/2016, 3:09:05 PM
googActiveConnection    true
bytesReceived   313234
bytesSent   40179
packetsSent 367
googReadable    true
requestsSent    7
consentRequestsSent 1
responsesSent   7
requestsReceived    7
responsesReceived   7
googChannelId   Channel-audio-1
googLocalAddress    50.97.253.78:52438
localCandidateId    Cand-OPB5vZ00
googLocalCandidateType  relay
googRemoteAddress   80.187.103.5:27515
remoteCandidateId   Cand-uraNsZG+
googRemoteCandidateType prflx
googRtt 778
packetsDiscardedOnSend  0
googTransportType   udp
googWritable    true
```